# Utilize Git Bash Command Values as Versioning Scheme Using Angular

Tags: git, shell, angularjs, versioning, githooks

I am inquiring to examine the possibilities of using values I receive while issuing git bash terminal commands within my web application to create a modified semantic versioning scheme utilizing AngularJS.

I retrieve my count by issuing

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

and abbreviated hash

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

These commands return values of interest to me, and now my question is, is it possible to somehow harvest these values in a usable way to reference within my page, and if so, is there a decent method to do this using Angular?

Comment: Not sure about C#, but it's gotta be there.  In PHP you have system() http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php, my basic understanding of this is that the command called will be executed as the user running the PHP script (in my case the web server users www-data), not sure what repercussions this will have with regard to git.

Comment: @shaunhusain I have included a solution that works if you are interested to view. Thank you for your contribution regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

While continuing to research the topic, I have encountered some gotchas in my first answer. For this project, executing pre-build commands in Visual Studio is conflicting with other team members due to the hard coded path for the git bash terminal varying per workstation. To remedy this, I have introduced the idea of utilizing [git hooks](http://githooks.com/), running a Shell Script upon a post-commit action in git. This method will ensure the task at hand will be accomplished universally, point to the local git bash on each workstation, alleviating the potential to break the build in case the git bash path varies (which is a likely case).

**Here is my new solution**

navigate in your local repo `.git > hooks > post-commit.sample` and replace with the following

```
revision=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD);

build=$(git rev-list HEAD --count); 

version=$"{"$'"build":''"'$build$'"'$","$'"revision":'$'"'$revision$'"'$"}"; 

echo $version > "YourWebProject\version.txt";
```

Ensure to rename `pre-commit.sample` to `pre-commit` which will make the script now executable upon the action. Once executed, we will have a generated text file structured like the following JSON object

```
{
    "build":"# representing your git commit count",
    "revision":"abbreviated hash for last commit"
}
```

**Create your Angular controller**

```
function VersioningCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('version.txt')
    .success(function (data) {
        if (data && status === 200) {
            $scope.version = {
                build: data.build,
                revision: data.revision
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div data-ng-controller="VersioningCtrl">
    Version 0.0.{{ version.build }}.{{ version.revision }}
</div>
```

**Another gotcha**

Due to the nature of this file being generated on the fly, I found it beneficial to include it within the git ignore file which was causing previous issues with git prompting me to always commit and track the new file.

I find this solution to be a bit more universal and efficient

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution (see second answer)**

**1. Your Solution > Right Click > Properties > Build Events > Edit Pre-Build:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" rev-list HEAD --count > "$(ProjectDir)build.txt"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" rev-parse --short HEAD > "$(ProjectDir)revision.txt"
```

This will create two text files upon your next build, in this case, `build.txt` and `revision.txt` which will be located inside your project folder. To then reference these files in your application

**2. Your Solution > Right Click > Add > Existing Item > Navigate to your text files**

**3. both text files > Right Click > Properties:**

`Build Action: Embedded Resource`

`Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always`

**4. Angular Controller**

```
function VersioningCtrl($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('revision.txt')
          .success(function (data) {
          if (data && status === 200) {
              $scope.revision = data;
          }
      });

     $http.get('build.txt')
          .success(function (data) {
          if (data && status === 200) {
              $scope.build = data;
          }
     });
}
```

**5. Markup**

```
<div data-ng-controller="VersioningCtrl">
    <p>Version 0.0.{{ build }}.{{ revision }}</p>
</div>
```